# Reading large formatted text file with NumPy

Tags: numpy, python-2.7

I've volunteered to help someone convert a finite element mesh from one format to another (i-deas *.unv to Alberta). I've used NumPy to do some additional shaping of the mesh, but I'm having problems reading the raw text file data into NumPy arrays. I've tried genfromtxt and loadtxt with no success so far.

Some details:

1) All groups are delimited by the header and footer flag "    -1" on its own line.

2) The NODE group has a header "  2411" on its own line. I only want to read alternate lines from this group, skipping each line with 4 integers, but reading the line with 3 Fortran double precision numbers.

3) The ELEMENT connectivity group has a header "  2412" on its own line. All data are integers and only the first 4 columns are required to be read. There will be some empty slots in the NumPy array due to missing values for 2 and 3 node elements.

4) The " 2477" node groups I think I can deal with myself using regular expressions that find which lines to read.

5) The real data file will have about 1 million lines of text, so I'm very keen for it to be vectorized if possible (or whatever NumPy does to read stuff quickly).

Sorry if I've given too much information, and thanks.

The lines below are a sample of parts of the *.unv text file format.

```
    -1
  2411
  146303         1         1        11
  6.9849462399269246D-001  8.0008842847097805D-002  6.6360238055630028D-001
  146304         1         1        11
  4.1854795755893875D-001  9.1256034628308313D-001  3.5725496189239300D-002
  146305         1         1        11
  7.5541258490349616D-001  3.7870257739063029D-001  2.0504544370783115D-001
  146306         1         1        11
  2.7637569971086767D-001  9.2829777518336010D-001  1.3757239038663285D-001
   -1
   -1
 2412
     9        21         1         0         7         2
     0         0         0
     1         9
    10        21         1         0         7         2
     0         0         0
     9        10
  1550        91         6         0         7         3
   761      3685      2027
  1551        91         6         0         7         3
   761      2380      2067
 39720       111         1         0         7         4
 71854     59536     40323     73014
 39721       111         1         0         7         4
 45520     48908    133818    145014
   -1
   -1
   2477
     1         0         0         0         0         0         0      3022
PERMANENT GROUP1
     7         2         0         0         7         3         0         0
     7         8         0         0         7         7         0         0
     7       147         0         0         7       148         0         0
     2         0         0         0         0         0         0      2915
PERMANENT GROUP2
     7         1         0         0         7         5         0         0
     7         4         0         0         7         6         0         0
     7         9         0         0         7        11         0         0
   -1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numpy methods `genfromtxt` and `loadtxt` would be rather difficult to apply on the whole file, as your data has a quite special structure (which changes depending in which node you are). Therefore, I'd suggest the following strategy:

- Read the file line by lines, try to determine in which node you are by analysing the line.
- If you are in a node, which has only a few data (and where, for example, you have to read alternating lines, so you can't read continously), read it line by line and process the lines.
- When you reach a section with a lot of data (like the one with the "real data"), use numpys fromfile method to read in the data, like this:

  ```
  mydata = np.fromfile(fp, sep=" ", dtype=int, count=number_of_elements)
  mydata.shape = (100000, 3)    # Reshape it to the desired shape as fromfile
                                # returns a 1D array.
  ```

This way, you combine the flexibility of line-by-line processing with the ability to quickly read and convert large chunks of data.

UPDATE: The point is, that you open the file, read it line by line, and when you arrive at a place with a big chunk of data, you pass the file descriptor to fromfile.

Below a simplified example:

```
import numpy as np

fp = open("test.dat", "r")
line = fp.readline()
ndata = int(line.strip())
data = np.fromfile(fp, count=ndata, sep=" ", dtype=int)
fp.close()
```

That would read the data from a file `test.dat` with a content like:

```
10
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

The first line is read explicitely with `fp.read()`, processed (the number of integers to be read is determined) and then `np.fromfile()` reads the appropriate chunk of data and stores it in the 1D-array `data`.

UPDATE2: Alternatively, you could read the entire text into a buffer, then determine the starting and end positions for the large chunk of data and convert it via `np.fromstring` directly:

```
fp = open("test.dat", "r")
txt = fp.read()
fp.close()
# Now determine starting and end positions (startpos, endpos)
# ..
# pass text that portion of the text to the fromstring function.
data = np.fromstring(txt[startpos:endpos], dtype=int, sep=" ")
```

Or, if it is easy to formulate as one regular expression, you could use the `fromregex()` directly on the file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Looking at the "fromfile" command it appears to read the file from the first line, and therefore wont allow reading just a specific block. I looked at using the "open" command to define a block for "fp" above, but that too seems to only read the file from the first line.

Comment: I added a simplified example above.

Comment: Thanks for spelling it out! The point I was missing was that the readline() command has the effect of telling the fromfile command that it should read fp from the current line not the start of the file. Is there a way to set the starting line to some value without having to call readline() multiple times? I can quickly find the line numbers at the start and end of a data block by searching for the string "     -1" at the start of a line, but having to call readline() in a loop to get to the required starting point would slow things down somewhat. Thanks!

Comment: Again, I extended the answer. :-)